# Swiftui - Multi-sheet content passing Item

Tags: swiftui

I'm trying to manage multiple sheet in the same view using an Enum to identify which view to show. The problem is that the sheet don't see the change on item sc2Edit when I set it by swipe action.

Am I using a wrong solution?

Here my test code:

```
import SwiftUI

extension Playground {
    enum SheetView: Int, Identifiable {
        var id: Self { self }
        case sheetColor = 1
        case sheetIcon = 2
        case sheetModify = 3
    }

    struct Item {
        var id: UUID
        var name: String
    }
}

struct Playground: View {
    @State private var showSheet: SheetView? = nil

    @State var sc2Edit: Item? = nil
    
    var body: some View {
        List(1..<10){ sc in
            Text("Test \(sc)")
                .swipeActions(allowsFullSwipe: false) {

                    Button {
                        sc2Edit = Item(id: UUID(), name: String(sc))
                        debugPrint(sc2Edit)
                        showSheet = .sheetModify
                    } label: {
                        Label("Edit", systemImage: "pencil")
                    }
                    .tint(.orange)
                }
        }
        .sheet(item: $showSheet, onDismiss: { showSheet = nil }){ sheet in
            switch sheet {
            case .sheetColor:
                Text("Testo1")
            case .sheetIcon:
                Text("Testo2")
                
            case .sheetModify:
                Text(sc2Edit?.name ?? "Testo")
            }
        }


    }
}

struct Playground_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        Playground()
    }
}
```